# What does this log file mean?

Tags: android, logfile, logfiles

I installed CWM recovery on my rooted Xperia P JellyBean. Now the app Rom Toolbox Pro by jrummy won't start. It just crashes every time I open it.

So I saved a log file using Logcat app.

Here it goes -

> 06-13 17:54:25.784 D/RomToolboxHelper(16322): com.aokp.romcontrol was
>   not found by packageManager 06-13 17:54:25.784
>   D/RomToolboxHelper(16322): com.cyanogenmod.cmparts was not found by
>   packageManager 06-13 17:54:25.784 D/RomToolboxHelper(16322):
>   com.noshufou.android.su was not found by packageManager 06-13
>   17:54:25.784 D/RomToolboxHelper(16322): com.jrummy.busybox.installer
>   was not found by packageManager 06-13 17:54:25.784
>   D/RomToolboxHelper(16322): com.jrummy.busybox.installer.pro was not
>   found by packageManager 06-13 17:54:25.784 D/RomToolboxHelper(16322):
>   com.tmobile.themechooser was not found by packageManager 06-13
>   17:54:28.526 E/RomToolboxHelper(16322): Failed reading news 06-13
>   17:54:28.526 E/RomToolboxHelper(16322): org.json.JSONException: No
>   value for id 06-13 17:54:28.526 E/RomToolboxHelper(16322):    at
>   org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354) 06-13 17:54:28.526
>   E/RomToolboxHelper(16322):    at
>   org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510) 06-13 17:54:28.526
>   E/RomToolboxHelper(16322):    at
>   com.jrummy.apps.rom.toolbox.a.i.run(Unknown Source)

What does it mean? Will I ever be able to run this Essential app?

Comment: I downgraded the app and it worked!